# Реализация сочетания клавиш в консоли

Tags: c#, .net

Подскажите, а как можно реализовать работу сочетаний клавиш в консоли?

Например, если набрать команду:

> ping "blablabla" /t

и через какое-то время сочетание CTRL+PAUSE, то вылетит статистика на текущий момент, но сам ping продолжит выполняться дальше => такой функционал реализуем.

Comment: [Может быть через WinAPI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3654787/global-hotkey-in-console-application/3654821#3654821)

Answer (score 1):

Конкретно для Ctrl+Break есть специальное событие [Console.CancelKeyPress](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.cancelkeypress?view=netcore-3.0). Произвольные сочетания клавиш можно реализовать, вызывая в цикле [Console.ReadKey](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.readkey?view=netcore-3.0):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    while (true)
    {
        var key = Console.ReadKey();
        if (key.Modifiers.HasFlag(ConsoleModifiers.Alt) && key.Key == ConsoleKey.A)
        {
            //Alt+A
        }            
    }
}
```